# Reading multiple words from the user/console using fread in Erlang

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, fread, erl

I want to read multiple words and store them in a variable using Erlang. When I use fread to record a string, it records only the first word.

```
1> {ok,[Message]} = io:fread("Type your message : ", "~ts").
Type your message : Hello world
{ok,["Hello"]}
2>  world
```

So "Hello" is saved to Message instead of "Hello world". How can I save both words to the variable message.

I'm looking for a general answer so that I can read in many words and not just 2 words, so please don't post answers for only 2 words.

---

**Desired output**

```
{ok,["Hello world"]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [io:get_line/1](https://erldocs.com/19.0/stdlib/io.html?i=0&search=get_line#get_line/1)

```
1> Line = io:get_line("Type your message: ").
Type your message: Hello world. Goodbye.
"Hello world. Goodbye.\n"

2> Line.
"Hello world. Goodbye.\n"

3> DesiredOutput = {ok, [string:strip(Line, right, $\n)]}.
{ok,["Hello world. Goodbye."]}

4> DesiredOutput.
{ok,["Hello world. Goodbye."]}
```

> Line:
>
> The characters in the line terminated by a line feed (or end of file).
>   If the I/O device supports Unicode, the data can represent codepoints
>   > 255 (the latin1 range).